# Get a text file name

Tags: python

7 on Windows 7 platform.

I would like to complete two steps,

1. generate a text file with the name of current date and time
2. get the size of this file.

So far, I could generate the file and know the command to get the size. The question is, before I use the command to get the text file size, I need to type in the file name. But I have no idea how to get it. Please see the two steps code in below for detail.

1) To generate a text file with name of current date and time:

```
import datetime
import os
import glob

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_{fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

with open(timeStamped('Log.txt'),'w') as outf:
     print outf
```

2) the command to get the file size:

```
size = os.path.getsize("path/file name")
```

I am stuck at second step: ("path/file name") because I cannot get the name of the text file.

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use function `input()`?

Comment: You already have a method that gets the filename. What's the problem?

Comment: Why are you opening the file in the first place, if you only need its size? You can print `outf.name` if you want to get the name but there is no reason to open your file just to get its size.

Comment: the reason i open a file first is to prepare writing some content in, and then check the size. Do you have any good idea about the structure? I am a Python newbie,  open to any advice. :) @zwer

Answer (score 2):

Just save the name of the file:

```
import datetime
import os

def timeStamped(fname, fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_{fname}'):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=fname)

fname = timeStamped('Log.txt')
with open(fname,'w') as outf:
     outf.write('something')

size = os.path.getsize(fname)
print(size)
```

Comment: Love it! Thumb up. Thanks Mark.

Comment: BTW, do you think if it is a good idea to saperate them as two different definitions? like 'def...'  'def...'